# Understanding the output of docker build command

Tags: docker, build, containers

I am trying to understand the output of a `docker build` command for popular images e.g. `node`. Here is the `Dockerfile` I used.

```
FROM node:10
```

Which `Dockerfile` refers to `node:10` in [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)?

The `docker build` command has the following output:

```sh
Step 1/1 : FROM node:10
10: Pulling from library/node
9a0b0ce99936: Pull complete
db3b6004c61a: Pull complete
f8f075920295: Pull complete
6ef14aff1139: Pull complete
0bbd8b48260f: Pull complete
524be717efb1: Pull complete
5216176a8ae7: Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                  30f1e4a2facd: Pull complete
823c0b3f4fa2: Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                  Digest: sha256:dabc15ad36a9e0a95862fbdf6ffdad439edc20aa27c7f10456644464e3fb5f08
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:10
 ---> e45bc9197ec9
Successfully built e45bc9197ec9
```

What do all the `Pull complete` refer to? The layer ID `e45bc9197ec9` refers to the final image. From a running container, is it possible to 'reverse lookup' `e45bc9197ec9` and get all the pull digests?

Answer (score -2):

OK. The Pull generally refers to the layer. Ideally a UFS - Union File System concept from Linux/Unix.
Every layer is disk mounted in layers. When you pull an image, the dependent file disks are mounted in reverse order - bottom to top.

You can read about UNIX Union File System - with mounts for more details.
Here the pull refers to each mountable disk package that gets downloaded and mounted
Think of this like a LEGO block with which you build a structure.

Reverse look up from top to bottom - am not sure which tool does that for you, ideally you log into your running container and get to see all your image dependencies are available.

Comment: OK. Will watch out for best answers then. Probably i couldnt get your question straight.